# How to translate native MongoDB Shell Aggregate into MongoDB Node.js Aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I have two equivalent codes.  One runs happily inside MongoDB's native shell:

```
db.analytics.aggregate([ 
   { $match: { firmware_version: '1.6.186' } }, 
   { $limit: 10 }, 
   { $out: "TestingNodeAggs" } 
], {allowDiskUse: true});
```

The other is intended to automate the shell script over a cron or similar app launching/scheduling service:

The problem with the second is that it doesn't seem to create the specified output collection!?!?

```
co(function*(){
    var db = yield MongoClient.connect('mongodb://path.to.mongo.db');
    var collection = db.collection('analytics');
    var cursor = yield collection.aggregate([
      { $match: { firmware_version: '1.6.186' } },
      { $limit: 10 },
      { $out: "TestingNodeAggs" }
    ], {allowDiskUse: true});
    var result = yield cursor.toArray();
    console.log(result); // Returns 'pending'
});
```

After the second script runs...I check for a TestingNodeAggs collection to no avail.  Can someone explain how I should be structuring my data automations with Node.js?